ApexChart Horizontal barchart Xaxis repetition Issue
I have set Custom Colors for 4 Ranges in Horizontal bar chart and values within each range have specific colors to distinguish, which are 4 Different Colors as Green Color, Yellow Color, Red Color and Black Color. As I set Custom Colors, the Xaxis value of Horizontal bar chart is repeating 2 times.

@using UIDesignBlazorApexChart.Client.Theme
@inject IThemeService ThemeService

<style>
    .apexcharts-tooltip {
        color: black;
    }

    .apexcharts-menu {
        color: black;
    }
</style>
<MudGrid>
    <MudItem xs="12">
<DemoContainer>

    <MudButtonGroup Color="MudBlazor.Color.Default" Variant="Variant.Filled" Size="MudBlazor.Size.Small" Style="margin-bottom:10px;">
                <MudButton FullWidth>@_buttonText</MudButton>
    <MudMenu Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.ArrowDropDown" Style="align-self: auto;">
        @foreach (var appName in AppNames)
        {
            <MudMenuItem OnClick="() => SetButtonText(appName)">@appName.Display</MudMenuItem>
        }
    </MudMenu>
</MudButtonGroup>
          
            <div Style="height:300px;background: radial-gradient(circle, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%, rgba(232,229,231,1) 100%);">
            <ApexChart Height="300" @ref=chart TItem="Risk" Title=@GetTitle()  Options=options Debug>

                <ApexPointSeries TItem="Risk"
                         Items="risks"
                     Name="Gross Value"
                     SeriesType="SeriesType.Bar"
                     XValue="@(e => e.Name)"
                     YAggregate="@(e => e.Sum(e => e.Value))"
                                 Color="#64DD17"
                                 PointColor="e=> GetColorForValue(e)" />
</ApexChart>
            </div>

</DemoContainer>
</MudItem></MudGrid>

@code {
    private string GetColorForValue(Risk risk)
    {
        if (risk.Value < 1.25M && risk.Value > 0)
        {
            return "#64DD17"; // Green
        }
        else if (risk.Value < 2.5M && risk.Value >= 1.25M)
        {
            return "#FFB300"; // Orange
        }
        else if (risk.Value < 3.75M && risk.Value >= 2.5M)
        {
            return "#FF0000"; // Red
        }
        else 
        {
            return "#424242"; // Gray
        }
    }
    private ApexChart<Risk> chart;
    private List<Risk> risks { get; set; } = new List<Risk>();
    private string _buttonText = "Quality Data Lake for Reliance from Hexagon ETQ being added to existing SaaS platform for Seeds Reliance";
    private ApexChartOptions<Risk> options;


    private async Task UpdateChart()
    {
        await chart.RenderAsync();
    }
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        risks = new List<Risk>();

        foreach (var item in SampleData.GetOrders())
        {
            risks.Add(new Risk { Name = item.Name, Value = item.Value });
        }

        base.OnInitialized();
        options = new ApexChartOptions<Risk>
            {
                PlotOptions = new PlotOptions
                {
                    Bar = new PlotOptionsBar
                    {
                        Horizontal = true
                    }
                },
                Theme = new Theme
                {
                    Mode = Mode.Light,
                    Palette = PaletteType.Palette1
                }
            };
    }
    
    private List<AppName> AppNames = new List<AppName>()
    {
        new AppName { Value = 1, Display = "Quality Data Lake for Reliance from Hexagon ETQ being added to existing SaaS platform for Seeds Reliance" },
        new AppName { Value = 2, Display = "Application of Smart Trac sensors with 3G/4G mobile network communication for the Tractian Platform"},
        new AppName { Value = 3, Display = "Leadscope Model Applier - Acute Toxicity QSAR Suite"},
        new AppName { Value = 4, Display = "Orion"},
        new AppName { Value = 5, Display = "SynGPT Web and Teams Version (Syngenta's Private ChatGPT Instance)" }
    };
    private int selectedApp = 1;
    private int selectedAppID = 1; // Default selection

    private string GetTitle()
    {
        return "Detailed Risk view for each application ";
    }

    private async Task SetButtonText(AppName selectedAppName)
    {
        _buttonText = selectedAppName.Display;
        selectedAppID = selectedAppName.Value;
        await UpdateChartAsync(selectedAppID);
    }
    private async Task SelectApp(AppName selectedAppName)
    {
        selectedApp = selectedAppName.Value;
        await UpdateChartAsync(selectedApp);
    }
        
    private async Task UpdateChartAsync(int selectedAppID)
    {
        GetOrdersAsync(selectedAppID);
        await chart.RenderAsync();
    }
    private async Task<List<Risk>> GetOrdersAsync(int selectedAppID)
    {
        // Replace this with the appropriate logic based on the selected app
        switch (selectedAppID)
        {
            case 1:
                return risks= await Task.FromResult(SampleData.GetOrders()); // Sample data for the first app
                break;
            case 2:
                return risks = await Task.FromResult(SampleData2.GetOrders()); // Sample data for the second app
                break; 
            case 3:
                return risks = await Task.FromResult(SampleData3.GetOrders()); // Sample data for the second app
                break;
            case 4:
                return risks = await Task.FromResult(SampleData4.GetOrders()); // Sample data for the first app
                break;
            case 5:
                return risks = await Task.FromResult(SampleData5.GetOrders()); // Sample data for the second app
                break; // Add cases for other apps as needed
            default:
                return risks = await Task.FromResult(SampleData.GetOrders()); // Default to the first app's data
                break;
                // Render the chart asynchronously
                await chart.RenderAsync();

        }
    }

    public class Risk
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public decimal Value { get; set; }
    }

    public class AppName
    {
        public int Value { get; set; }
        public string Display { get; set; }
    }

    public static class SampleData
    {
        public static List<Risk> GetOrders()
        {
            var risks = new List<Risk>
            {
                new Risk { Name = "InformationSecurityPolicy", Value = 1.45M },
                new Risk { Name = "OrganisationOfInfoSecurity", Value = 1M },
                new Risk { Name = "HumanResourceSecurity", Value = 1M },
                new Risk { Name = "AssetManagement", Value = 1.8M },
                new Risk { Name = "AccessManagement", Value = 1.45M },
                new Risk { Name = "Cryptography", Value = 1.6M },
                new Risk { Name = "PhysicalEnvironmentalSecurity", Value = 1M },
                new Risk { Name = "OperationsSecurity", Value = 1.25M },
                new Risk { Name = "CommunicationsNetworkSecurity", Value = 1.6M },
                new Risk { Name = "SystemAcquisitionDevMaintenance", Value = 3.8M },
                new Risk { Name = "SupplierRelationships", Value = 1.25M },
                new Risk { Name = "InformationSecurityIncidentManagement", Value = 1.75M },
                new Risk { Name = "BusinessContinuityManagement", Value = 3.2M },
                new Risk { Name = "LegalandRegulatoryRisk", Value = 1M }
            };
      
            return risks;
        }
    }
    public static class SampleData2
    {
        public static List<Risk> GetOrders()
        {
            var risks = new List<Risk>
            {
                new Risk { Name = "InformationSecurityPolicy", Value = 3.45M },
                new Risk { Name = "OrganisationOfInfoSecurity", Value = 1.35M },
                new Risk { Name = "HumanResourceSecurity", Value = 1M },
                new Risk { Name = "AssetManagement", Value = 2.8M },
                new Risk { Name = "AccessManagement", Value = 1.45M },
                new Risk { Name = "Cryptography", Value = 2.6M },
                new Risk { Name = "PhysicalEnvironmentalSecurity", Value = 1M },
                new Risk { Name = "OperationsSecurity", Value = 1.25M },
                new Risk { Name = "CommunicationsNetworkSecurity", Value = 1.6M },
                new Risk { Name = "SystemAcquisitionDevMaintenance", Value = 1M },
                new Risk { Name = "SupplierRelationships", Value = 1M },
                new Risk { Name = "InformationSecurityIncidentManagement", Value = 1.75M },
                new Risk { Name = "BusinessContinuityManagement", Value = 2.5M },
                new Risk { Name = "LegalandRegulatoryRisk", Value = 1M }
            };

            return risks;
        }
    }
    public static class SampleData3
    {
        public static List<Risk> GetOrders()
        {
            var risks = new List<Risk>
            {
                new Risk { Name = "InformationSecurityPolicy", Value = 2.45M },
                new Risk { Name = "OrganisationOfInfoSecurity", Value = 1M },
                new Risk { Name = "HumanResourceSecurity", Value = 1.8M },
                new Risk { Name = "AssetManagement", Value = 1M },
                new Risk { Name = "AccessManagement", Value = 1.6M },
                new Risk { Name = "Cryptography", Value = 1.45M },
                new Risk { Name = "PhysicalEnvironmentalSecurity", Value = 1M },
                new Risk { Name = "OperationsSecurity", Value = 3.8M },
                new Risk { Name = "CommunicationsNetworkSecurity", Value = 1.6M },
                new Risk { Name = "SystemAcquisitionDevMaintenance", Value = 2M },
                new Risk { Name = "SupplierRelationships", Value = 1.25M },
                new Risk { Name = "InformationSecurityIncidentManagement", Value = 1.75M },
                new Risk { Name = "BusinessContinuityManagement", Value = 3.2M },
                new Risk { Name = "LegalandRegulatoryRisk", Value = 1M }
            };

            return risks;
        }
    }
    public static class SampleData4
    {
        public static List<Risk> GetOrders()
        {
            var risks = new List<Risk>
            {
                new Risk { Name = "InformationSecurityPolicy", Value = 1.45M },
                new Risk { Name = "OrganisationOfInfoSecurity", Value = 1M },
                new Risk { Name = "HumanResourceSecurity", Value = 1.8M },
                new Risk { Name = "AssetManagement", Value = 1M },
                new Risk { Name = "AccessManagement", Value = 1.6M },
                new Risk { Name = "Cryptography", Value = 1.45M },
                new Risk { Name = "PhysicalEnvironmentalSecurity", Value = 1M },
                new Risk { Name = "OperationsSecurity", Value = 3.8M },
                new Risk { Name = "CommunicationsNetworkSecurity", Value = 1.6M },
                new Risk { Name = "SystemAcquisitionDevMaintenance", Value = 3.5M },
                new Risk { Name = "SupplierRelationships", Value = 1.25M },
                new Risk { Name = "InformationSecurityIncidentManagement", Value = 1.75M },
                new Risk { Name = "BusinessContinuityManagement", Value = 3.2M },
                new Risk { Name = "LegalandRegulatoryRisk", Value = 1M }
            };

            return risks;
        }
    }
    public static class SampleData5
    {
        public static List<Risk> GetOrders()
        {
            var risks = new List<Risk>
            { 
                new Risk { Name = "InformationSecurityPolicy", Value = 2.45M },
                new Risk { Name = "OrganisationOfInfoSecurity", Value = 1M },
                new Risk { Name = "HumanResourceSecurity", Value = 1.8M },
                new Risk { Name = "AssetManagement", Value = 1M },
                new Risk { Name = "AccessManagement", Value = 1.6M },
                new Risk { Name = "Cryptography", Value = 1.45M },
                new Risk { Name = "PhysicalEnvironmentalSecurity", Value = 1M },
                new Risk { Name = "OperationsSecurity", Value = 3.8M },
                new Risk { Name = "CommunicationsNetworkSecurity", Value = 1.6M },
                new Risk { Name = "SystemAcquisitionDevMaintenance", Value = 2M },
                new Risk { Name = "SupplierRelationships", Value = 1.25M },
                new Risk { Name = "InformationSecurityIncidentManagement", Value = 1.75M },
                new Risk { Name = "BusinessContinuityManagement", Value = 3.2M },
                new Risk { Name = "LegalandRegulatoryRisk", Value = 1M }
            };

            return risks;
        }
    }
}


I want X-axis as 0, 0.5,1,1.5,2,2.5,3,3.5,4..... But it is displaying as 0,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4....  I have tried using apexchart nuget package as well as apexchart.js facing the same issues in both sides. How to Fix This Issue?
